# Any Stock Trading using Bitcoin?

Tags: economic-theory, bitcoin-economy

I would imagine Bitcoin is the perfect tool for students to learn about economic and learn about investing. Any out there available yet?

Answer (score 3):

There are a few currently operating Bitcoin security exchanges with non-negligible volumes:

---

**Cryptostocks**
https://cryptostocks.com/

Opened at the end of June 2012. Run by the owners of Vircurex, a fairly popular alt-currency exchange.

---

**Bitfunder**
https://bitfunder.com/

Launched mid-December 2012. Run by the owners of Hashpower, a mining intermediary of sorts.

---

**BTC Trading Corporation (BTC-TC)**
https://btct.co/

Currently in beta. Launched in November 2012 by the owners of Litecoin Global (a Litecoin-based security exchange; not affiliated with or related to Bitcoin Global, the GLBSE parent company).

---

**MPEx**
http://mpex.co/

Opened in August 2011. By far the largest of these in terms of (claimed) combined asset market cap and trading volume, but not at all newbie-friendly. Run by Mircea Popescu.

---

The Bitcoin stock exchange scene collapsed into utter chaos after GLBSE shutdown unceremoniously. You'll find many assets listed on multiple exchanges, some assets still being transferred from GLBSE, and some former GLBSE assets currently not actively traded on any exchange.

Try, learn, and have fun, but *caveat emptor* (buyer beware). Read the contracts carefully; make sure you know exactly what you're buying. Research the asset issuer in detail, particularly their past history, before you purchase. Don't equate legal identification with trustworthiness. If you're unsure about anything, ask someone more experienced for their advice - most are glad to help. Last but not least, never under any circumstances invest more than you can afford to lose.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately [GLBSE](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/GLBSE) was mismanaged and closed down. AFAIK there is nothing like that now. Unless I've misunderstood the question.

Answer (score 0):

I've noticed the lack of creditable material in this space and thus have committed to developing a curriculum with Jeff Tucker and a few others to relate Bitcoin to conventional economics for our free course:

https://www.udemy.com/bitcoin-or-how-i-learned-to-stop-worrying-and-love-crypto/

If something else does exist that isn't highly subjective or peer reviewed, then I'd be surprised. Most websites drafting material about Bitcoin have a POV skew. There also is a general lack of academic articles about Bitcoin thus creditable research is hard to come by.